# Accessing class from Wordpress filter

Tags: wordpress, filter, plugins

I'm probably making a mess of this...

I'm trying to add a filter to the_content that will add a method from an external class, but keep going round in circles.

Can anyone point me in the right direction??

```
class MyClass {

    var foo;
    var bar;

    function myMethod($id) {
            // some code
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on accessing `myMethod($id)` from within a plugin filter like so:

```
function extendPost($content, '') {
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $class = new MyClass();
    // this is where i get stuck
    $myMethod = $class->myMethod($id) // ??;
    $content.= "<div>" . $myMethod . "</div>";
}

add_filter('the_content', 'extendPost');
```

Any help would be ace. I'd really like to get some sleep tonight ;)

Comment: Do you actually have a `return` statement in your `myMethod` function that returns a value to assign your `myMethod` variable?

Comment: Also, not sure if this is because of your post or your actual code, but you commented out the ';' on the line $myMethod is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

`add_filter()` takes a [standard PHP callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php) as an argument.

To apply the `extendPost()` method of the *object* `$myObject`;

```
add_filter('the_content', array(&myObject, 'extendPost'));
```

To apply the `extendPost()` method of the *class* `myClass`;

```
add_filter('the_content', array('myClass', 'extendPost'));
```